# R plumber JSON serializer auto_unbox

Tags: json, r, plumber

Following the example on the page http://plumber.trestletech.com/

I wrote myfile.R as

```
#* @post /test
test <- function(){
list(speech='aa',source='bb',displayText='cc')
}
```

And I ran the plumber code on it to convert int into an API

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("~/Work/myfile.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

And Now when I perform an POST request on it using I get

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:8000/test
-> {"speech":["aa"],"source":["bb"],"displayText":["cc"]}
```

But I want the square brackets to be removed. In simple toJSON calls it can be done using auto_unbox=TRUE but how can I do it in plumber. 
How can I write a custom serializer and use it in the above code?

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). Post a piece of code that produces exactly the output that you already show. For this example, you could do `toJSON(fromJSON('{"speech":["aa"],"source":["bb"],"displayText":["cc"]}'), auto_unbox = TRUE)` to get rid of the square brackets.

Comment: Added the example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured the process to add custom serializers.
Let's say we want to make a custom serializer for JSON and name it "custom_json"
myfile.R would be

```
#* @serializer custom_json
#* @post /test
test <- function(){
list(speech='aa',source='bb',displayText='cc')
}
```

And while running plumber code it would go as

```
library(plumber)
library(jsonlite)

custom_json <- function(){
  function(val, req, res, errorHandler){
    tryCatch({
      json <- jsonlite::toJSON(val,auto_unbox=TRUE)

      res$setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
      res$body <- json

      return(res$toResponse())
    }, error=function(e){
      errorHandler(req, res, e)
    })
  }
}

addSerializer("custom_json",custom_json)
r <- plumb("~/Work/myfile.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

And Now when I perform an POST request on it using I get

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:8000/test
-> {"speech":"aa","source":"bb","displayText":"cc"}
```

Comment: Already available in `plumber::serializer_unboxed_json`. See the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

Plumber provides a [number of serializers](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/rendering-and-output.html#serializers) out of the box. `unboxedJSON` is [one of them](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/rendering-and-output.html#boxed-vs-unboxed-json).

Simply use the `@serializer unboxedJSON` annotation on you endpoint.

You can also set the default serializer to be `plumber::serializer_unboxed_json`.